# SafeCracker #1 - Look who's talking

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence, algorithm

[image: SafeCracker]

### The Plot

You work for a tech company in Tampa, FL. Recently there was a break-in, and the company's trade secrets were stolen.

Company PI have tracked the briefcase containing the secrets to the building you are in now. They are in three different places.

### Task 1

Decypher Keycode and open first safe.

[image: KeyPad 1]

> **Safe 1 Instructions**

Unless you know the combo, you need to use their backdoor. That involves answering a challenge question...
[image]
**Question:**
Your college professor thinks of two consecutive numbers between 1 and 10.  There are two students nearby, and he has promised automatic A++ for their final exam to whomever guesses correctly.

The first student knows one number and the second student knows the second number. The following exchange takes place:

*First Student:* I do not know your number.

*Second Student:* Neither do I know your number.

*First Student:* Now I know.

There are 4 possible solutions. Append the 4 solutions to make one number **from largest to smallest**.  This will be the safe combination.

> Time running out...

**WHAT IS THE COMBO?**

When the correct combination is entered, the second in this series will be posted.

**Good Luck!**

---

> Welcome to my SafeCracker series. I used to write similar programs in
>   Assembly for others to try to "crack" back in the day. I thought it fun to re-visit. And please try solving yourself before Googling, as of course, this question similarly will be posted somewhere on the net. Try first! :)

Comment: Is the second number the greater one, or can it be either way?

Comment: Well, since the numbers will be consecutive, it doesn't matter. But when you find all 4 numbers, you must arrange them largest to smallest to obtain the safe combination. Good Luck,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is:

> **9887**

because

> The first student's number (x) cannot be 10, because they would know that the second student's number (y) is 9. However, x=9 and y=8 works. In the same way, x=8 and y=7 works. Since you said that there were four numbers, I don't need to continue!

### EDIT

> x=3 and y=2 could also work as well as x=4 and y=3, but the four **largest** are above...

Comment: great work. Thank you for posting your workflow you used, so others can see how you came to the solution. Nice work. Thanks for participating..

Comment: @JohnS. Thanks! When's the next part?

Comment: since you found the first of the three "cases" , then I suppose it's time to head on over to SafeCracker #2. This house has much better security, lol. See you tomorrow!

Comment: Wonderful! I can't wait!

Answer (score 1):

Is the code

> **9832?**

I'm going to call the students A and B, and their numbers a and b.

> * a is not 10. Otherwise the first statement is false.
>  * a can be 9. If b is 8, then the conversation makes sense.
>  * a can be 8. If b were 9, then B could deduce that a is not 10 from the first statement, and know A's number. However, B doesn't know it, which is why A knows b can not be 9, and therefore knows that b must be 7.
>  * a is not 4,5,6 or 7. The first two statements wouldn't give A enough information to deduce B's number.
>  * a can be 3. This is exactly symmetrical with the possibility of a=8.
>  * a can be 2. Symmetrical with a=9.
>  * a is not 1. Symmetrical with a=10.

Comment: I am new here, so I am unsure how to answer that. Do I post the answer as a "Hint" like you did, or can I respond via private message? In short, however, no unfortunately that is not correct.

Comment: @JohnS. there are no private messages on Stack Exchange. The usual method is to wait for the correct answer, possibly giving hints in the comments, or if no-one answers, at about 24h intervals in the question itself. Once someone posts an acceptable answer, you click on the "accept" checkmark on the left side of that answer. (Also, I fixed my off-by-one error :-)

Comment: !> You got the first two

Comment: @JohnS. and not the symmetrical cases? I must be missing something very silly then.